# How to use srun command to assign different GPU for each task in a node with multiple GPUs?

Tags: slurm

How can I change my slurm script below so that each python job gets a unique GPU? The node had 4 GPUs, I would like to run 1 python job per each GPU.
The problem is that all jobs use the first GPU and other GPUs are idle.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --qos=maxjobs
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH --exclusive


for i in `seq 0 3`; do
    cd ${i}
    srun python gpu_code.py &
    cd ..
done
wait
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example your four jobs will be executed sequentially. I suggest submitting four separate jobs that only request a single GPU. Then the jobs only use one GPU and will be executed simultaneously. If the jobs have depencies you can use:
`sbatch --dependency=afterok:${jobid_of_previous_job} submit.sh`. This job will start after the prvious has finished.

Comment: Thanks @nameiki, but I am looking for a solution to this specific question without changing the question itself.

Comment: Welcome @A.Razavi what exactly are you trying to achieve? The way I understand your question is that you want to submit a job with four GPUs and then run 4 sequential jobs using one GPU each one after another. This would mean that you only use a quarter of the GPUs. If these four jobs should be executed simultaneously you should submit four different jobs.

Answer (score 0):

As you do not request GPUs in the submission scripts, you will have to manage the [CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-control-gpu-visibility-cuda_visible_devices/) var by yourself to direct each python script to one specific GPU.

Try with

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --qos=maxjobs
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH --exclusive


for i in `seq 0 3`; do
    cd ${i}
    export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$i
    python gpu_code.py &
    cd ..
done
wait
```

Comment: Is there a way not to use `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`? What if I want to run 8 jobs simultaneously and the node had only 4 GPUs? Is there a way to changes run or SBATCH lines to achieve the same goal?